# Debugging cross domain POST request from Facebook canvas

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, debugging

I'm fairly new as a web developer. 
I have a form that POST from a Facebook Canvas app (belonging to a third party service) to a file on my server. And then put the response in an iframe:

```
  <iframe style="width: 0px; height: 0px;" name='theiframe' src='...'> </iframe>
<form  style="display: none;" id='mandrill_form' action="https://www.mysite.com/myfile.php" method="POST" target='theiframe'>
 <input id='mandrillSend' type="text" name="email"><br>
  <input id='nameSend' type="text" name="user"><br>
  <input id='addressSend' type="text" name="address"><br>
  <input id='zipSend' type="text" name="zip"><br>
   <input id='citySend' type="text" name="city"><br>
  <textarea id='other' type="text" name="other"> </textarea><br> 
  <input id='premieInfo' type="text" name="premieInfo"><br>
  <input  id='mandrillTemplate' type="text" name="template"><br>
  <input id='mandrillSubmit' type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Everything works great for most of the users but 7% of the posts never reach myfile.php. (I keep track of all the user clicks, and the browsers with a third party Facebook plugin on the canvas page and a log file on my server). It dosen't seems to have anything to do with a specific browser.

I'm using the jQuery **.submit()** function to send the form.

**My question is:**
How should I go on debugging to find what causes this 7% loss of cross domain POST requests?

Comment: I don’t see what submitting a normal form even has to do with the CORS headers … And I don’t get how many iframes are now actually involved here. OK, one from FB, into which your app gets loaded. And what happens then? Please be more specific in your description of what happens, where and in what order.

Comment: You're right, I should try to be more specific. My main problem is that I can't understand why it dosen't work all the time. 

1. A user posts a form from inside a Facebook canvas app (iframe).
Data travels from that to my server (on an other domain) and back.
2. Result gets displayed inside a second iframe located inside the FB iframe.

I just don't get why it dosen't work 100% of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Losing 'traffic' like this is very normal.
You can see it in the advertisements companies. They almost every time losing 10% of the traffic.
But that how the internet works. You just can't catch them all.